# TYPO3 fluid viewhelper f:security.nonce doesn't generate nonce

Tags: typo3, fluid, view-helpers

While playing around with CSP directives in TYPO3 12.4.13 I stumbled upon a bit of a weird issue. To run inline scripts I have defined a nonce value for my script-src directive using the TYPO3 extension specific approach. In my fluid template I use the f:security.nonce() viewhelper to generate to correct nonce value. However, in some cases the viewhelper doesn't generate a nonce value.

Here are some examples of those cases. Note that the extra f:secity.nonce() viewhelper is just for testing purposes. 
In this case the viewhelper correctly works:

```html
{f:security.nonce()}  <!-- Outputs hash 0NnkfpY8... -->
<script nonce="{f:security.nonce()}">
    let map;

    async function initMap() {
        // Map
        map = new Map(document.getElementById("map"), {});
    }

    initMap();
</script>
```

But when adding something like `zoom: 14,` to the `Map` object, the viewhelper doesn't generate anything:

```html
{f:security.nonce()} <!-- Outputs {f:security.nonce()} -->
<script nonce="{f:security.nonce()}">
    let map;

    async function initMap() {
        // Map
        map = new Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
            zoom: 14,
        });
    }

    initMap();
</script>
```

Here's another example:
Like this the viewhelper works:

```html
{f:security.nonce()} <!-- Outputs hash 0NnkfpY8... -->
<script nonce="{f:security.nonce()}">
    let map;

    async function initMap() {
        // Set map constants
        const centerPosition = { lat: xxx, lng: xxx },
              mapStyle = "xxxxxx"; 
        const markerPosition = centerPosition;
    }

    initMap();
</script>
```

But like this it doesn't:

```html
{f:security.nonce()} <!-- Outputs {f:security.nonce()} -->
<script nonce="{f:security.nonce()}">
    let map;

    async function initMap() {
        // Set map constants
        const centerPosition = { lat: xxx, lng: xxx },
              mapStyle = "xxxxxx",
              markerPosition = centerPosition;
    }

    initMap();
</script>
```